# Raspberry pi throws UnsatisfiedLinkError when experimenting with Pi4J

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, pi4j

I am a Minecraft server admin trying to get a discord bot running that turns the Minecraft server on. I would like to run the bot on my Raspberry Pi and run it using Java. However, my GPIO library doesn't really work, throwing UnsatisfiedLinkErrors all the time when I try to run my testing program, even after checking all dependincies (like pigpio, wiringpi, pi4j, ...). What could still be wrong?

Here is a screenshot of the error: [image: Error msg]

Edit: 32bit Raspberry Pi OS doesn't work, but now the error is different (No such file or directory). I have not checked all dependencies though, so that may be the issue now.

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly. 
One of the lines (which I can't quote from as you posted a picture) suggests you've got the wrong libraries for your processor architecture

Comment: Looks like an improper mix of 32 bit and 64 bit software.

Comment: @Holger that could indeed be it, since the Pi4J website reccomends 32bit Raspian, and I use 64bit

Comment: gonna try flashing with 32bit then

Comment: @Holger can you please make your comment an answer, that seemed to be the solver (after reinstalling WiringPi)